# AJAX request works locally but not in production

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, routes

I have a really weird problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I have an AJAX request that works perfectly locally but does not work on Production. The goal of this ajax call is to show a little more info of a certain profile when the user clicks on a 'expand info' (you can find a similar logic on Linkedin on each contact profile)

The only difference between local and production is:

- Locally I have an extra url slug 'localhost/extra_slug/drupal/urls/' (since is a MAMP subfolder)

Databases are exactly the same.

Any idea?

```
function personal_info_show_form($form, &$form_state, $profile) {
    // Set the id to identify this as an profile edit form.
    $form['#id'] = 'personal-info-form';
    // Save the profile for later, in case we need it.
    $form['#profile'] = $profile;
    $form_state['profile'] = $profile;

    $form['user_id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $profile->user_id,
    );

    // Add the buttons.
    $form['buttons'] = array();
    $form['buttons']['#weight'] = 100;
    $form['buttons']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Contact Info'),
        '#weight' => 5,
        "#ajax" => array(
            "callback" => "ajax_personal_info_show",
            "wrapper" => "personal-info-replace",
            "effect" => "fade",
        ),
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('button')),

    );

    return $form;
}
```

And here is the callback:

```
function ajax_personal_info_show($form, &$form_state)
{
    $html .= '';
    $html .= '<div id="personal-info-replace">';


    $query = db_query(' select mail, phone from users, profile
                        where users.uid = profile.user_id
                        and users.uid = '.$form_state['values']['user_id'].';');
    $info = $query->fetchObject();

    $html .= '<div class="data">';
    if (property_exists($info, 'mail'))
        $html .= '<div class="field">email</div><div class="value">'.$info->mail.'</div>';

    if (property_exists($info, 'phone'))
        $html .= '<div class="field">phone number</div><div class="value">'.$info->phone.'</div>';

    $html .= '</div>';
    $profile = load_user_profile($form_state['values']['user_id']);
    $form = drupal_get_form('personal_info_close_form', $profile);
    $html .= drupal_render($form);
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}
```

Update, added server responses:

This is the response on production:

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","jquery":{"ui":{"datepicker":{"isRTL":false,"firstDay":0}}},"ajaxPageState":{"theme":"project_name","theme_token":"TbevKg4_EXU1ERHQXhU2NCysl0HRxzgmyggl5MbCj4k"}},"merge":true}]
```

And the response on locally (working):

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/project_name\/","pathPrefix":"","jquery":{"ui":{"datepicker":{"isRTL":false,"firstDay":0}}},"ajaxPageState":{"theme":"project_name","theme_token":"8biI4MmRocc38QZ3nyuTwhQk7yFHaPbc87ugREkHYFA"},"ajax":{"edit-submit--3":{"callback":"ajax_personal_info_close","wrapper":"personal-info-replace","effect":"fade","event":"mousedown","keypress":true,"prevent":"click","url":"\/project_name\/system\/ajax","submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"op","_triggering_element_value":"Close"}}}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":null,"selector":null,"data":some_data_here","settings":null},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":null,"data":"","settings":null}]
```

Comment: What does your JS console show? What does "does not work" mean here? No request sent? Request sent but invalid data returned? No data returned? And so on.

Comment: Hi @Mołot, I added the Server responses.

Comment: OK, now things got interesting :D Good luck with it. Sadly, the difference does not look like anything I have encountered myself, so can't help you now :(